# get comment during iteration in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

How can I get the comments when I iterate through the YAML object

```
yaml = YAML()

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    yaml_data = yaml.load(f)

for obj in yaml_data:
    # how to get the comments here?
```

This is the source data (an ansible playbook)

```
---
- name: gather all complex custom facts using the custom module
  hosts: switches
  gather_facts: False
  connection: local
  tasks:
    # There is a bug in ansible 2.4.1 which prevents it loading
    # playbook/group_vars
    - name: ensure we're running a known working version
      assert:
        that:
          - 'ansible_version.major == 2'
          - 'ansible_version.minor == 4'
```

After Anthon comments, this is the way I found to access the comments in the child nodes (needs to be refined):

```
for idx, obj in enumerate(yaml_data):
    for i, item in enumerate(obj.items()):
        pprint(yaml_data[i].ca.items)
```

Comment: Next time please leave out the thanks, but include a complete example, including some real YAML data (with comments), so we don't have to guess what your input looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify your input, but since your code expects an `obj` and
not a key, I assume the root level of your YAML is a sequence and not mapping.
If you want to get the comments after each element (i.e `nr 1` and `the last`) you can do:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- one  # nr 1
- two 
- three # the last
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)

for idx, obj in enumerate(data):
    comment_token = data.ca.items.get(idx)
    if comment_token is None:
        continue
    print(repr(comment_token[0].value))
```

which gives:

```
'# nr 1\n'
'# the last\n'
```

You might want to strip of the leading octothorpe and trailing newline.

Please note that this works with the current version (0.15.61), but
there is no guarantee it might not to change.

Comment: I added the source yaml file. With your code I cannot get the comments

Comment: That is because the comments are not on the root-level datastructure. I still have no clue what kind of output you expect, or what you want to do with that. Do you just want a dump of all the comments in the order they appear in the YAML document?

Comment: I need to create some documentation from the playbooks we used, so I need to iterate through the document and get some info. One of the info that I need are the comments. I have to put them in another dictionary that will be used later in the code I'm writing

Comment: You continue to be vague and imprecise: "In another dictionary" What is the first dictionary you are referring to? As you can see from the last line in my code the comments are in a list there. If you want them in a dictionary, are the comments the keys, or the values? And what is going to be value resp. the key in for each comment, given one or the other.

Comment: I'm vague and imprecise because I'm trying to understand the object returned from your library and if I can or not get the comments (the most important thing). Anyway your solution points me in the right direction, I only have to add another for loop to get the comments from the tasks

Comment: There is no standardized interface, as the comment attachments (alwasy on the `.ca` attribute) are there to support the round-tripping, and were not designed to extract the data. That currently all hangs of a `.ca` attribute of a `CommentedMap` (loaded from YAML mappings) or `CommentedSeq` (loaded from YAML sequence). But where on the `.ca` datastructure depends on where on original the comment occured (end-of-line, before first element/key, after a key) etc. There is no documentation for that, sorry. Just pring the `.ca` attribute and compare with the original YAML

Answer (score 2):

Using the [example from Anthon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52045749/4941585) as well as [an issue in ruamel.yaml on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/tickets/293/#0a5b), here's a set of methods which should allow you to retrieve (almost - see below) all the comments in your documents:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap, CommentedSeq

# set attributes
def get_comments_map(self, key):
    coms = []
    comments = self.ca.items.get(key)
    if comments is None:
        return coms
    for token in comments:
        if token is None:
            continue
        elif isinstance(token, list):
            coms.extend(token)
        else:
            coms.append(token)
    return coms

def get_comments_seq(self, idx):
    coms = []
    comments = self.ca.items.get(idx)
    if comments is None:
        return coms
    for token in comments:
        if token is None:
            continue
        elif isinstance(token, list):
            coms.extend(token)
        else:
            coms.append(token)
    return coms

setattr(CommentedMap, 'get_comments', get_comments_map)
setattr(CommentedSeq, 'get_comments', get_comments_seq)

# load string
yaml_str = """\
- name: gather all complex custom facts using the custom module
  hosts: switches
  gather_facts: False
  connection: local
  tasks:
    # There is a bug in ansible 2.4.1 which prevents it loading
    # playbook/group_vars
    - name: ensure we're running a known working version
      assert:
        that:
          - 'ansible_version.major == 2'
          - 'ansible_version.minor == 4'
"""
yml = YAML(typ='rt')
data = yml.load(yaml_str)

def walk_data(data):
    if isinstance(data, CommentedMap):
        for k, v in data.items():
            print(k, [ comment.value for comment in data.get_comments(k)])
            if isinstance(v, CommentedMap) or isinstance(v, CommentedSeq):
                walk_data(v)
    elif isinstance(data, CommentedSeq):
        for idx, item in enumerate(data):
            print(idx, [ comment.value for comment in data.get_comments(idx)])
            if isinstance(item, CommentedMap) or isinstance(item, CommentedSeq):
                walk_data(item)

walk_data(data)
```

Here's the output:

```
0 []
name []
hosts []
gather_facts []
connection []
tasks ['# There is a bug in ansible 2.4.1 which prevents it loading\n', '# playbook/group_vars\n']
0 []
name []
assert []
that []
0 []
1 []
```

Unfortunately, there <s>are two</s> is one problem<s>s</s> that I have encountered which are not covered by this method:

1. You will notice that there is no leading \n in the comments for `tasks`. As a result, it is not possible with this method to differentiate between comments which start on the same line as `tasks` or on the next line. Since the `CommentToken.start_mark.line` only contains the absolute line of the comment, it might be able to be compared to the line of `tasks`. But, I have not yet found a way to retrieve the line associated with `tasks` inside the loaded data.
2. <s>There does not seem to be a way that I have found yet to retrieve comments at the head of the document. So, any initial comments would need to be discovered using a method other than to retrieve them outside the yaml reader. But, related to problem #1, these head comments are included in the absolute line count of other comments.</s> To add the comments at the head of the document, you need to use `[comment.value for comment in data.ca.comment[1]` as per [this explanation by Anthon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66821036/4941585).