# Python Ruamel YAML - how to get comments of merged portions

Tags: ruamel.yaml

If I load this sample YAML file:

```
aliases:
  - &a1
    b1: 5         # Comment for b1=5
    c1: 3         # Comment for c1=3

model:
  obj1:
    <<: *a1
    d1: 7         # Comment for d1=7
  obj2:
    *a1
  obj3:
    *a1
```

With this code:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

with open("test.yaml") as fp:
    d = yaml.load(fp, yaml.RoundTripLoader)

def showcmts(d):
    for k,v in d.items():
        print("Key {} has {}".format(k, (d.ca.items[k][2] if k in d.ca.items and d.ca.items[k][2] is not None else "no comment")))

print("Model obj1 contents and comments are:")
showcmts(d["model"]["obj1"])
print("Model obj2 contents and comments are:")
showcmts(d["model"]["obj2"])
print("Model obj3 contents and comments are:")
showcmts(d["model"]["obj3"])
```

I get this output:

```
Model obj1 contents and comments are:
Key d1 has CommentToken('# Comment for d1=7\n', line: 8, col: 18)
Key b1 has no comment
Key c1 has no comment
Model obj2 contents and comments are:
Key b1 has CommentToken('# Comment for b1=5\n', line: 2, col: 18)
Key c1 has CommentToken('# Comment for c1=3\n\n', line: 3, col: 18)
Model obj3 contents and comments are:
Key b1 has CommentToken('# Comment for b1=5\n', line: 2, col: 18)
Key c1 has CommentToken('# Comment for c1=3\n\n', line: 3, col: 18)
```

How do I get the comments associated with `obj1/b1` and `obj1/c1`?  The comments are getting loaded and read correctly for `obj2/b1`, etc., but I need them to also be there for `obj1/b1`, etc.

Comment: Where did you get the example to load the YAML using `d = yaml.load(fp, yaml.RoundTripLoader)`? You should be using the new API (using a `YAML()` instance), which  was introduced a few years ago.

Comment: Good question - I see the docs for the current version reference the YAML() instance method.  This code is only a couple months old.  I BELIEVE I started with the example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043027/get-comment-during-iteration-in-ruamel-yaml and then added the RoundTripLoader bit after looking to fix exporting.  I'll update my code for the YAML() method.

Comment: That example already uses the new API. I was just curious if I could update (or recommend updating) some example to make sure people start with the new API (it allows for more control, especially on output, than I could put in the old API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ruamel.yaml, using the round-trip loader/dumper, doesn't really merge mappings. It keeps them
seperate, so they can be dumped back as separate entities, but provides special versions of
key/value access on the object constructed from the "mapping with merges" that acts as if that is a dict.

So you need to do to two things:

- distinguish between real keys and merged-in keys
- access the comment of a merged-in key

Please be aware that to do so you need to access undocumented internals which
may change without notice. Pin your production code to the specific YAML version
with which you are developing.

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml


def showcmts(d):
    def pkc(k, d):
        print("Key {} has {}".format(k, (d.ca.items[k][2] if k in d.ca.items and d.ca.items[k][2] is not None else "no comment")))

    for k in d:
        if k in d._ok:  # Own Keys i.e. not merged-in
            pkc(k, d)
            continue
        for pos, merge in d.merge:
            if k in merge._ok:
                pkc(k, merge)
                break
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
d = yaml.load(Path('test.yaml'))

print("Model obj1 contents and comments are:")
showcmts(d["model"]["obj1"])
print("Model obj2 contents and comments are:")
showcmts(d["model"]["obj2"])
print("Model obj3 contents and comments are:")
showcmts(d["model"]["obj3"])
```

which gives:

```
Model obj1 contents and comments are:
Key d1 has CommentToken('# Comment for d1=7\n', line: 8, col: 18)
Key b1 has CommentToken('# Comment for b1=5\n', line: 2, col: 18)
Key c1 has CommentToken('# Comment for c1=3\n\n', line: 3, col: 18)
Model obj2 contents and comments are:
Key b1 has CommentToken('# Comment for b1=5\n', line: 2, col: 18)
Key c1 has CommentToken('# Comment for c1=3\n\n', line: 3, col: 18)
Model obj3 contents and comments are:
Key b1 has CommentToken('# Comment for b1=5\n', line: 2, col: 18)
Key c1 has CommentToken('# Comment for c1=3\n\n', line: 3, col: 18)
```

Comment: That works well, thanks.

Is it worth mu adding a feature request ticket to make the comments object work the same way as the data objects do (so not needing this code)?

Comment: ruamel.yaml if for round-trip, preserving comments. The comments are for humans, to understand the actual data. If there is something in the comments that a computer program should know, then the data is incomplete and/or defined inflexible. Given that premise, IMO you are abusing the library to compensate for faulty/incomplete data if you need to compare data and comments. So this is unlikely to be facilitated by an extension in the instantiated classes (and hence my recommendation to pin the version of ruamel.yaml used).